# Failure to run the program made by pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I just converted .Py and successfully generated .exe file. When tried to launch,the application windows immediately closed without any error

win 10,python2.7
May I know what went wrong with the program?

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you just run it like that, the moment the program finishes, the window will close.

Comment: First, move to Python 3, then if it still doesn’t work read the chapter “When things go wrong” in the documentation https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 2):

you probably need to run the executable from inside a CMD.
Unless you used some kind of a UI package, simply clicking on the exe file will open a CMD window that will be closed immediately on error or when the program is finished.

To run it, open a cmd and just type the file's name (with full path).

Answer (score 1):

Try with Python 3. Python 2 support has ended and recent versions of PyInstaller do not support Python 2 any more.

Answer (score 0):

I also tested it with Python 3, but it didn't work again
No script responds
I made a "Hello World" script, but it did not open
Please, if you can help, it is very, very important to me
I got a project, I am currently stuck in this stage

Comment: I fixed it. I changed the version pynput pip install pynput==1.6.8